# Store SQL in MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, wordpress

My technical blog didn't get off to a good start as Wordpress wouldn't save my post that contained PHP, HTML and SQL code.  I'll have to modify Wordpress sanitation methods or roll my own basic blogging platform but what is the correct and safe way to store technical text with this kind of content in a MySQL database?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using php.
Best is to use PDO, see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

**From that site**
Example #1 Prepare an SQL statement with named parameters

```
<?php
/* Execute a prepared statement by passing an array of values */
$sql = 'SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour';
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
$sth->execute(array(':calories' => 150, ':colour' => 'red'));
$red = $sth->fetchAll();
$sth->execute(array(':calories' => 175, ':colour' => 'yellow'));
$yellow = $sth->fetchAll();
?>
```

Example #2 Prepare an SQL statement with question mark parameters

```
<?php
/* Execute a prepared statement by passing an array of values */
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < ? AND colour = ?');
$sth->execute(array(150, 'red'));
$red = $sth->fetchAll();
$sth->execute(array(175, 'yellow'));
$yellow = $sth->fetchAll();
?>
```

**Alternatively use escaping**

Use `mysql_real_escape_string()` to escape values before inserting them into the query.

```
$val1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['value1']);
$query = "SELECT a,b,c FROM table1 WHERE a = '$val1' ";
// the quotes are essential                  ^     ^
```

**Outputting code as code**
When outputting the content use:

```
echo "the output is: ".htmlentities($output);
```

Comment: I am looking to store text content (a webpage) in the database that contains php, js, html, sql code within that content. Code samples as here on SO.  Wordpress doesn't like it, so will need to modify/write my own sanitation that enables all code samples to be safely saved within a MySQL database field

Comment: @MattP The **only** sanitation you need is `mysql_real_escape_string()`.